# Trying to write two games in one code by PYGAME

Tags: pygame

I need to make the main menu where I can press 1 to play one game and 2 to another game. I already have two while loops for games, but have no idea how to write it in one code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you ask a question here, you need to give a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimum-reproducible-example). A Minimum reproducible example is the only way we can help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate each of the game's main loops with functions. First you can create a GUI window. One of the most common and easy GUI windows to use is `tkinter`. Import it at the top of you code with `from tkinter import *`. You could create a simple GUI like this:

```
global window
window = Tk()
window.title("Choose Game")
GAbutton = Button(window, text="Game One", width=10, command=GameOne)
GAbutton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
GBbutton = Button(window, text="Game Two", width=10, command=GameTwo)
GBbutton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
```

The `command` is the name of the function. Full code could look like:

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame
def GameOne():
    window.destroy()
    #Your first game goes here

def GameTwo():
    window.destroy()
    #Your second game goes here

global window
window = Tk()
window.title("Choose Game")
GAbutton = Button(window, text="Game One", width=10, command=GameOne)
GAbutton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
GBbutton = Button(window, text="Game Two", width=10, command=GameTwo)
GBbutton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
```

All you need to do is to make sure that each game is in the same indentation level as the comment.

Comment: I wrote in every def full code of my game and run program ,but it does not do anything..

Comment: Attack your full code @MoodyLover and I will put it in for you...

Comment: I wrote window.mainloop() in the end, so it works. Thank you so much! I don't know what I would have done without your help...

Comment: Ah yes - I probably should have included that. Would you mind giving my answer a tick @MoodyLover .

Comment: how to give a tick?

Comment: There is a tick symbol underneath the voting section. click it and it will go green @MoodyLover